# iCal - Strange events generated by Thunderbird

Tags: parsing, events, outlook, icalendar, thunderbird

I'm working on a iCal parser, written in C++. In this context I noticed several events, all generated by Thunderbird, that my parser is unable to parse correctly.

Here is a sample for one of these events:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20170111T221139Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20170111T221145Z
DTSTAMP:20170111T221145Z
UID:882f4c15-03e9-451c-bf4f-b3422ed8ef54
RDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20170111T163000Z
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20170111T173000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20170111T173000
X-MOZ-FAKED-MASTER:1
X-MOZ-GENERATION:1
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20170106T215137Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20170111T221145Z
DTSTAMP:20170111T221145Z
UID:882f4c15-03e9-451c-bf4f-b3422ed8ef54
SUMMARY:Obst
RECURRENCE-ID;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20170111T173000
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20170111T194500
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20170111T201500
SEQUENCE:7
TRANSP:OPAQUE
X-MOZ-GENERATION:12
END:VEVENT
```

I noticed several special features on this event:

- The main event does not contain summary, only the linked exception contains one.
- The start and end dates are equals.
- The main event does not contain any recurrence rule (RRULE), but it contains a recurrence date (RDATE).
- The recurrence date in the main event is located 30 minutes before the event start date and time.

I tried to import it in Google Calendars and Outlook. In Google Calendars, the event appears on the correct date and time, with an alarm set to 30 minutes before the event. With Outlook (2013) I could only import the event partially, and the error message shown on the screenshot below appears. I suppose that only the 2nd VEVENT was imported, as the first is the one that no contain title.

[image: The event imported in Outlook]

I cannot figure out how this event is built. For that I have several questions:

- Is this event generated correctly, or it may be a bug in the Thunderbird calendars?
- A RDATE pattern may exist without a RRULE? Is this make a sense?
- Should the date in the RDATE pattern be considered as an alarm instead of an occurrence of an eventual recurrence?
- What is the relationship between the main event and his exception in this case, as the main event does not contain any recurrence rule beyond the RDATE pattern, which seems not a real recurrence rule?
- What may mean the undocumented X-MOZ-FAKED-MASTER attribute? It is in relation with the way this strange event was built?

Comment: This is a well-written question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a standard perspective a recurring event can perfectly be represented by using only RDATE(s) and no RRULE. Some legacy clients like Lotus Notes always translate recurrence rules into a series of RDATE. See how you are supposed to do the calculation at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.2
In practice, most recent clients do not handle recurring events containing RDATE(s) very well. They may display them correctly but will fail to present a way to edit them.

From your screenshot it looks like this is what Outlook is complaining about (unsupported recurrence pattern).

As to this particular event, it looks indeed quite funky as this is basically a recurring event with just one instance. What makes it even more funky is that there is an exception attached to this single instance which overrides the SUMMARY/DTSTART/DTEND. But that does not make it invalid.

(Please note that SUMMARY is not mandatory in a VEVENT).

Now this event is invalid but for other reasons:

1. The RDATE should use the same format as the DTSTART/DTEND, i.e. local time with timezone
2. As you mentioned, the DTSTART and DTEND can not be equal as per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.2.2

Comment: Thx for this answer, that allows me to decide a good strategy to apply to manage this kind of events correctly.